# How to monitor and validate response data of python REST app hosted at gcp with kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform

At my company we have a Python app which exposes rest APIs. I need to periodically check if APIs are functioning and return the correct data in their responses.
So far I managed to configure Stackdriver uptime Checks - to check the statuses, 
But how, for example can I check if response "data" property is not an empty array (empty array is not valid)

```
{data:[]} //not valid - should have at least 1 item
```

Is uptime checks a good tool for it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Stackdriver's Uptime Check's cannot parse a JSON response for any sort of liveness / validity.

The only content check that it can do, is a basic "exists" check on the string data. If you know there's something that will always be returned; you could check for that. If your array is a list of strings, you could check for `"`.

However, that may feel a little "hacky".

Instead, you could use a scheduled cloud function that would handle more sophisticated checks; though this would require additional work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Stackdriver for this type of checking. I prefer to use Cloud Functions scheduled by Cloud Scheduler.

By using Cloud Functions I can write complex code to call my APIs and process the results. I then use Gmail to issue status reports in HTML format highlighting errors in red with a summary as the subject. This provides a great deal of functionality that is very easy to develop and test.